# PHP File Upload.. retrieve URL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to upload a file and then I want to grab it's URL so I can add it to a database. How can I get the new file's URL into a variable that I can use to insert via MySQL?

```
<?php
// Configuration - Your Options
  $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types     of file that will pass the validation.
  $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
  $upload_path = './files/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file   extension).
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

// Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

// Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

// Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

// Upload the file to your specified path.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
     echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; 
// It worked.
  else
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving the file to a location on your site:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)`

That is`$upload_path . $filename` is your relative URL to the file. You can prepend your site URL to get absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Files uploaded in php are stored in a temporary place/directory for further processing.
So you can very well get it's present url from,

```
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
```

this is the url you give it store the copy of the file in your server location.
If you want to specify a default loaction for the files uploaded via your php application, 
you can define it in Php.ini file -> edit -> upload_tmp_dir element to your wish 
Hope that helped :)

Comment: The tmp-location is worthless as it's removed after the upload is completed. See husbas's answer for the solution.

Comment: @OptimusCrime both are same $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] copying it is just a way around.It's a simple question & simple answer.